# Using Dylibs Inside App Bundle

Tags: xcode, linker, dylib

I am trying to compile an app that uses multiple libraries using Xcode. To do so, I created a script that copies all of my `.dylibs` from a location on my computer to the `Frameworks` folder inside my app bundle.
After adding the necessary `linker flags` and `header search paths`, I must now add my `library search paths`.

Since I have copied all the libraries inside my Frameworks folder of my app bundle, I have deduced that I must add `$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)` to the `library search paths` setting. Adding this fails, because the linker can not find that directory.

I am guessing that the `Frameworks` folder isn't created until after searching the `library search paths` setting. If so, how am I supposed to use the libraries that I have copied inside my app bundle?

Comment: Is your problem that compilation fails, or that the app won't run after being compiled?

Comment: It won't compile because it can't find the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the `.dylib` files in the `Frameworks` folder is something you do so that the application can find them when it runs.. `dylib` files are dynamically linked, so the application loads them at run time.

Setting Xcode up to link to the .dylibs at compile time should just be a matter of dragging the `.dylib` from the Finder into your Xcode project. I've shown this with a simple example project that uses libxar.dylib in the attached screenshot.

[image: Example of a dylib in an Xcode Project]

Comment: So I must have 2 copies of my dylib files right? One copy in the project folder and the other one in my app bundle? And if I want to use the dylib files from my app bundle, I must also set the Runpath Search Paths to $(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)?

Comment: @Cubia The copy that lives in your app bundle is there so that when you distribute the app bundle to someone else they get a copy of the dylibs so that they can actually run the app. You shouldn't need to set the search paths if the install path for the dylibs is set correctly. Are you building the dylibs yourself, or did you get them from someone/somewhere else?

Comment: I built the dylibs myself, and I made sure the dylib ID is set to @executable_path/../Frameworks/libmydylib.dylib. Is that the right thing to do?

Comment: Well thank you! You've just made things a lot clearer for me :)